# Change navigation bar icons

Tags: customization

I have a Nexus 6 that I am currently playing with which has the "soft key" navigation buttons on the bottom of the screen. It has a triangle for the back button, a circle for the home button and a square for recent apps button.

I also have an HTC One that has the same on screen navigation but the icons are a lot better looking in my opinion. It has a curved arrow for the back button, a picture of a Home for the Home button and overlapped squares for the recent apps button.

Is it possible to change the icons on the Nexus 6 without modding/jailbreaking the phone?

Comment: Not without modifying/rooting/custom rom

Comment: @xangua you might want to elaborate alittle (i.e. adding why, how to once rooted, etc.) and repost your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted.